# How to create image slideshow effect

Tags: iphone, slideshow

I m trying to do slideshow effect in iPhone as like in iTunes. One Image at the middle and the others at the left and ride side arranged in the manner of floppies in rack. but I not even a single clue for that. Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're talking about "coverflow" rather than "slideshow"...  if that's right, there are some libraries to help you: here's one I found by searching for "coverflow replacement":

http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this effect using the .transform property of CALayers. All iPhone UIViews have a CALayer, and you can apply 3D perspective transformations using a transform matrix like this:

```
CATransform3D m = CATransform3DIdentity;
m.m34 = -0.006;
[[containerView layer] setSublayerTransform: m];
```

The views within containerView will now have a perspective distortion applied! Instant coverflow affect. Just move the views to the left and right by changing their frames.